# how can move everything except 'tindog' to right side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Tindog</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

how can I move everything except tindog to the right side?
here I have used the bootstrap navbar version 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add bootstrap class **justify-content-end** in below div.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, adding `d-flex`to the class

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto d-flex">
```

If that doesn't work, try it on the surrounding div instead

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

Comment: both the method dose not work for me

Comment: OK so you could try `d-flex` on the Collapse div and then on the UL have `class="justify-content-end`